# Как запустить Long Poll?

Tags: php, бот, long-poll

Появилась необходимость подключится к (User) Long Poll в ВКонтакте. Все бы ничего, но есть одно непонимание. Создаю файл **index.php** и в нем **бесконечный цикл**, все работает. НО! Работает только тогда, когда я перехожу к этому **index.php** например в браузере, т. е. **кто-то должен подключится к .php файлу чтобы запустить сам Long Poll**.

Почему бы не оставить вкладку открытой 24/7? Сервер сбрасывает соединение в течении 60 секунд.
А почему бы не поставить cron задачу что бы каждую минуту стучал на сервер? Можно, но я считаю что это в корне плохой подход, и есть более правильное решение, помогите разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: Почему бы не подключиться к сверверу через SSH чтобы запустить фоновую службу стандартными средствами ОС без всех этих костылей с вкладками и кроном?

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Comment: https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82+%D0%B2+%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%3F